# IGFS replacement for storing files in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite, file-storage

I have been searching for a way where I can store my csv files in apache ignite and found IGFS and then discovered it was not in the version I am using currently. I wanted to ask is there a similar way to store files?

Comment: Why do you need to store files in Apache Ignite? Maybe you need to use e.g. S3 or HDFS?

Comment: I was actually thinking Apache ignite has something similar to HDFS

Comment: No. You may wish to stick with actual HDFS.